# Database design choice : Order Belongs To Invoice Or Invoice Belongs To a Order

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

there is a website which used to sale physical products ... now they want to sale some king of service which is completely different .... like credit packages to charge user account(to buy products)  or buy sms .. stuff like that

so db used to look like this

```
order : user_id  ,date , total_price 
order_items : order_id , item_id , quantity , price
invoice : order_id , price , settled 
Invoice_transactions : invoice_id , amount , date
```

basically invoice belongs to orders

now they want to sale services  , so we have to create 2 `orders` table

```
product_orders (it used to be orders)
service_orders
```

now i have to choose a design for invoice table

i can add add another field to indicate type pf the order

```
invoice : order_id , order_type , amount
          1        , product    , 10000
          1        , service    , 10000
```

which somehow doesn't feel right ... or i can add invoice id to orders

```
invoice :  order_type , amount , date
product_orders : invoice_id , date , total_price
service_orders : invoice_id , service_id , date , total_price
```

which one(if any) seems to be more reasonable design ?
here is products table : 
[image]

here is what service tables would look like :

[image]

here is orders (which should change to product order ) 
[image]

here is what service_order would look like
[image]

Comment: I suspect that an order could have more than one invoice over time, for instance, if the first invoice is not paid or if the order changes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no , thats what transactions are for , we have 1 invoice and they can pay it in multiple transactions over the time (check out Invoice_transactions table )

Comment: Please add table schema for items/products and services. I would like to know, if they can be merged to one table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel services are credit  packages to charge user account  (basically they end up buying physical products with that credit.. is hsould have said credit instead of service !  ) ... i dont have schema for it yet but i'll create something

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i've added schema , let me know if anything is missing

Comment: Why did the selling of services necessitate splitting orders into two tables?  Why can't the order table cover both product orders and service orders?  Are product orders and service orders specialized sub-classes of orders?

Comment: @WalterMitty well in the product orders there are lots of extra steps and data invlolved like delivery , confirmation and also product change or rejection .... but services are just added to user account as soon as they buy them so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that both product orders and service orders have more in common than they have in difference. Within the greater business and financial ecosystem, they likely share the same roles/functions. So my first instinct to have a single table for both kinds of orders.

## One-To-One tables

Another route is to have simply one `order_` table, with a column indicating which type of order named something like `order_type_` containing values like `sales` or `products`.

Move all the product-related columns to a separate child table, `product_info_`. Move all the sales-related columns to a separate child table, `service_info_`. I would make `order_` table the parent to both, though technically we have a One-To-One relationship. For any given `order_` row we have exactly one `product_info_` row or exactly one `service_info_` row.

This might minimize duplication of data in the database and coding in your app. Your app code uses the flag field `order_type_` to query one or the other child table appropriately when you need the product or service details.

The invoices table links against the orders table. I assume invoicing works pretty much the same for both types of orders.

## All fields in Order

Another alternative is simply including all the product *and* service fields within the `order_` table. Simply ignore the product-related fields for the service orders, and ignore the service-related fields for the product orders. Not the most elegant, but if you have relatively few fields, and perhaps prefix the column names with `prod_` and `serv_`, this may be practicable. I have certainly done this more than once.

Comment: thanx , i was thinking about the `One-To-One tables` option ... its a relatively big system and need lots of upgrade and maintenance over time so my priority is to have a clean , explicit and flexible  design ... so apart from this you think i should have order_id in invoice table or other way around ? (i think with this re-defining of orders  i would keep order_id in the invoice table as before )

Comment: @hretic Are you issuing an invoice to bill the customer for the completed orders? If so, the order drives the business and invoice comes later, so the `invoice_` table should be a child of the `order_` table. And usually in a billing system you may have multiple invoices sent as billing for a single order. So it would be a One-To-Many relationship, parent order to children invoices.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to achieve with it, can a customer buy both in one order? The most common is what you did with invoice with an order_type it will have the least duplication

Comment: no they cant buy them in the 1 order ,  wel the duplicate order_id values and the fact that i cant have any foreign key constraint  on these tables is  kinda put off

Comment: @hretic in that case I would go for the order_type in the table invoice

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try to do:

Table `types`

```
type_id | name
      1 | product
      2 | service
```

Table `items` would have common columns for both - products and services.

```
items: item_id, type_id FK(types.type_id), price, title, ...
```

Tables `products` and `services` with FK `item_id` and columns that are not common for both types (like `products.weight`).

Add `type_id` column to the `orders` table:

```
order : user_id, date, total_price, type_id FK(types.type_id)
```

Add `type_id` column to the table `order_items`:

```
order_items: order_id, item_id, type_id, quantity, price
```

The FKs would be:

```
(order_id, type_id) -> orders(order_id, type_id)
(item_id, type_id) -> items(item_id, type_id)
```

With those FKs it's not possible to mix different types in one order.

Comment: what table is `items` ? do you mean `order_items` ?

Comment: @hretic No. As I wrote, It's a table with common columns for products and services. Like a superclass in OOP (`class Item {...}` - `class Product extends Item {...}` - `class Service extends Item {...}`). So you can have a FK to this table in `order_items`.